# Swift error using initialized properties in expressions before super.init

Tags: swift, properties, initialization

This isn't critical, and there are workarounds, but it is perplexing.

See the minimal example below.  I'm referring to an initialized property, but before calling super.init().   Why does the indicated statement below have a compile error?  Is there something special about using the property in the right hand of an expression versus the left hand?

I looked through the Swift language guides and couldn't find anything relevant. Is the swift compiler screwing up here, or is there something about properties, self, and init that I'm missing?  Or should *all* references to "myProperty" be in error before calling super.init?

(Note it doesn't matter if the property is a constant (with 'let') or if the property is another type, like an Int - the same thing happens.)

```
class MyClass : NSObject {
    var myProperty: Bool

    override init() {
        myProperty = true

        if myProperty { /* this is ok */ }
        if myProperty || true { /* this is ok */ }
        if true || myProperty  { /* this is NOT ok! ('self used before super.init') - WHY? */ }

        super.init()

        if true || myProperty  { /* now this is ok */ }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a side-effect of `||` being declared as

```
func ||<T : BooleanType>(lhs: T, rhs: @autoclosure () -> Bool) -> Bool
```

So the compiler treats

```
true || myProperty
```

as

```
true || { self.myProperty }()
```

The reason is the *"short-circuiting"* behaviour of the `||` operator: If the first
operand is true, then the second operand must not be evaluated at all.

(*Side note:* I assume that this is simplified at a later stage in the
 compiling/optimizing process
so that the final code does not actually create and call a closure.)

Accessing `self` inside the closure causes the error message. You would
get the same error for

```
override init() {
    myProperty = true
    let a = { self }() // ERROR: self used before super.init
    super.init()
    let b = { self }() // OK after super.init
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, that explains both the asymmetry and why the RHS is different from the other non-expression usage, in pulling in the "self" reference.  Amazing how much complexity underlies this "clean-and-simple" language!   Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is [intended behavior](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) and part of the two phase initialization.

This is a result of the following rules:

- All **properties must be initialized before super.init** is called, that is at the same line as the declaration or in init before super.init
- An initializer **may not** call any instance methods, **read the values of any instance properties**, or refer to self as a value **until after the first phase of initialization is complete**

Comment: By this logic, the first two 'if' statements should also be in error, as they refer to the value of an instance property before Phase 1 is complete. So the question would still be open, only reversed:  is this a Swift bug that the first 2 'if's are accepted?

Comment: True, in that case I would expect your other two statements to fail as well.