# Strange "'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized" error

Tags: swift

Please take a look at the following code:

```swift
class A {
    let a: String
    let b: String

    init(a: String, b: String) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    }
}

class B: A {
    let c: Bool

    private let aExpectedValue = "a"
    private let bExpectedValue = "b"

    override init(a: String, b: String) {
        c = (a == aExpectedValue && b == bExpectedValue)
        super.init(a: a, b: b)
    }
}
```

This causes an error in `B.init`:

[image: error]

However, if I change it either to `c = (a == aExpectedValue)` or `c = (b == bExpectedValue)` then it compiles correctly.

Does anybody know why is that?

Comment: `[a|b]ExpectedValue` are instance properties, i.e. linked to the `self`, and you can't use `self` in `init` until you initialise it properly.

Comment: @user28434 then why it works with `c = (a == aExpectedValue)` only?

Comment: Related: [What caused 'Constant captured by a closure before being initialized' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291580/what-caused-constant-captured-by-a-closure-before-being-initialized-error) and [Swift error using initialized properties in expressions before super.init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27302281/swift-error-using-initialized-properties-in-expressions-before-super-init)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is in `bExpectedValue`. That's an instance property on `B`. That interacts with the definition of `&&` on Bool:

```
static func && (lhs: Bool, rhs: @autoclosure () throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool
```

The `@autoclosure` makes the `b == bExpectedValue` into a closure, capturing it as `self.bExpectedValue`. That's not allowed before initialization is complete. (The closure here is to allow short-circuiting. The rhs closure is not evaluated if lhs is false.)

This is pretty awkward (see [SR-944](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-944) that MartinR references for a little discussion about it).

If `bExpectedValue` were `static`, or if it were moved outside the class definition, then this wouldn't be an issue. The following approach will also fix it:

```
override init(a: String, b: String) {
    let goodA = a == aExpectedValue
    let goodB = b == bExpectedValue
    c = goodA && goodB
    super.init(a: a, b: b)
}
```

Comment: So the same issue as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291580/what-caused-constant-captured-by-a-closure-before-being-initialized-error ?

Comment: Thanks Rob, that was exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new initializer with another vars or call super.init(a:, b:) before any expression with this properties.

Call this:

```
override init(a: String, b: String) {
    super.init(a: a, b: b)
    c = (a == aExpectedValue && b == bExpectedValue)        
}
```

or change it to:

```
init(newA: String, newB: String) {
    c = (newA == aExpectedValue && newB == bExpectedValue)        
    super.init(a: newA, b: newB)
}
```

Comment: Cool, REALLY quick answer, thanks! But the point is not how to workaround, I want to know why this happens.

Comment: the latter I cannot do, because I get `Argument labels for initializer 'init(newA:newB:)' do not match those of overridden initializer 'init(a:b:)'`

Comment: You have vars in method like property's names, You should change vars of method.

Comment: Sorry, I removed `override`

Comment: You need to create a new initializer with another vars or call super.init(a:, b:) before any expression with this properties.

Comment: Still, the question was not how to workaround but what is the root cause.